# Solving Project Euler 15 efficiency issue

Tags: java

The problem is as follows:

> Starting in the top left corner of a 2×2 grid, and only being able to move to the right and down, there are exactly 6 routes to the bottom right corner. How many such routes are there through a 20×20 grid?

My code is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BigInteger twenty = factorial(new BigInteger("20"));
    System.out.println(choose(twenty.add(twenty),twenty));
}
public static BigInteger choose(BigInteger n, BigInteger k){
    return factorial(n).divide(factorial(n.subtract(k)).multiply(factorial(k)));
}
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n){
    BigInteger num = BigInteger.ONE;
    if(n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    else{
        BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (i.compareTo(new BigInteger(n+"")) <= 0){
            num = num.multiply(new BigInteger(i+""));
            i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

This works for the example given, but of course takes a very long time to calculate the answer for the 20x20 grid. I get that the possible paths is equal to a+b choose a. The only problem is my code takes a long time. Is there anyway to increase the efficiency of my program?

Comment: You are calculating the factorial recursively, and then dividing factorials. Try to work it out on paper and see if something cancels out - and then think on how you could avoid computing all that self-cancelling part. Also, think about keeping a table of intermediate factorials, to avoid re-calculating them.

Comment: Your inputs `n` and `k` just needs to be `int`, not `BigInteger`. Sure, *result* may need `BigInteger`, but inputs very likely don't.

Comment: Tucuxi, how would one go about canceling things like that? Are there any good resources on this topic?